# Using async when two requests have to be made and response from the first is needed in the other request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, axios

I have a async function like this:

```js
exports.myFunction = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (some condition) {
     next()
  }

  try {

    const results = await axios.get(`https://a-domain.com/url/path`);
    const info = results.data;

    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "name_of_collec"), info);
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
  }

  next();
};
```

Here, response from the first request is required in the second request. But according to my knowledge since I am making asynchronous requests, the two requests should be made at the same time.
What I cannot understand:

- So, how it is possible that there is no error occurring?
- How is it that, sometimes the no document is added to Firestore? Like it is skipped somehow...
- What modification can be done so that `await addDoc(collection(db, "name_of_collec")` executes compulsorily?

Context info:

- I am using Express.js and Node.js to make a backend
- I am using Axios to make the first request and the second one is adding a document to Firestore.
- Firestore is a NoSQL database inside Google's Firebase.

Comment: *according to my knowledge* ... *the two requests should be made at the same time* - update your knowledge ... `await` waits for the promise to resolve before the next line of code can execute

Answer (score 0):

> But according to my knowledge since I am making asynchronous requests,
> the two requests should be made at the same time.

`asynchronous` doesn't mean that the requests are made at the same time. It means the code won't wait for the responses from these requests. Requests are made in the manner you add them in the code and responses will be asynchronous i.e the response will be received at some point in future time.

And there is no guarantee in what manner they will be received.

However, when you sue `async/await`, the code execution waits at await keyword for the response based on its success or failure it calls the next flow. It is nothing but syntactic sugar on promises. Under the hood, this is how your code will be executed:

```
exports.myFunction = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (some condition) {
     next()l
  }

  axios.get(`https://a-domain.com/url/path`).then(result => result).then(data => {
      const info = data;
      
      addDoc(collection(db, "name_of_collec"), info).then(response => {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
      })
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  })

   next();
};
```

> So, how it is possible that there is no error occurring?

It is not necessary that the error occurs when you request. If that is the case catch handler should be activated.

> How is it that, sometimes the no document is added to Firestore? Like
> it is skipped somehow...

The reason might be `info` is an empty object and firestore automatically removes the empty document.

There is no issue, but there is not data `info` that is empty sometimes that skips the addition(it does request firestore, but firestore removes the empty docs)

```
exports.myFunction = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (some condition) {
     next()
  }

  try {

    const results = await axios.get(`https://a-domain.com/url/path`);
    const info = results.data;
    const is_Info_Data = Array.isArray(info) ? info?.length >= 1: Object.keys(info) !== 0 
    if (is_Info_Data) {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "name_of_collec"), info);
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    } else {
      console.log(`Info is empty ${info} no addition to DB`);
    }
    
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    next(e);
  }

};
```

Comment: Can you **please** add modification of my code to solve the issue --- "The reason might be info is an empty object and firestore automatically removes the empty document."

Comment: Please check the answer now.

Comment: It must be such that, the document is written to Firestore. So how can that be achieved. Even if I have to do it without aync-await, I have to get the documents added to firestore

Comment: When you say: the document is written to Firestore? It doesn't add the document to firestore even if the info is present?

Comment: Did not understand your last comment. Your answer very good, but what it does not address the issue in my last comment. What ever needs to be done, the document must be added to firestore.

Comment: The document will only be added when you pass the data to the firestore add function else it won't add a new document.

Comment: I understand now, Firestore does not store empty documents. So, what can be done to make sure, `info` is not empty before trying to add it to firestore.

Comment: I have added that piece of code in the answer where we are checking if `info` is an array or object and if it is empty or not.

Comment: Can this be solved using `.then` syntax???

Comment: No, It can't because you need to check the info is array or object.

Comment: I am sure that `info` is an object.